# cannot get the element even after page load with ```document.getElementById()``` in react and keeps giving an error?

Tags: reactjs, dom, react-hooks

I am trying to take user input with a checkbox of weather, the user wants to get the emails from the website for new offers and updates or not, but when I define the element it keeps giving me error again and again, I have tried `window.onload()`, `useEffect`, `useRef` hook but my element keeps giving an error, it says `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'checked')` ,

here is the code.

with `getElementById()` :

```
  let wantEmailAndUpdates;
  useEffect(() => {
    if (document.getElementById("wantEmailAndUpdates").checked) {
        wantEmailAndUpdates = document.getElementById("wantEmailAndUpdates").value;
    }
  }, [])
```

the input code

```
<label className="ContactInformationFormAccountEmailTitleEmailNewsCheckbox">
    <input type="checkbox" value={true} id='wantEmailAndUpdates' name='wantEmailAndUpdates' checked />
    Email me with news and offers
</label>
```

with `useRef` hook :

```
  const wantEmailAndUpdatesRef = useRef(null)
  useEffect(() => {
    if (wantEmailAndUpdatesRef.current.focus().checked) {
      wantEmailAndUpdates = wantEmailAndUpdatesRef.current.focus().value;
    }
  }, [])
```

the input code

```
<label className="ContactInformationFormAccountEmailTitleEmailNewsCheckbox">
    <input type="checkbox" value={true} ref={wantEmailAndUpdatesRef} id='wantEmailAndUpdates' name='wantEmailAndUpdates' checked />
    Email me with news and offers
</label>
```

Comment: `wantEmailAndUpdatesRef.current` will give you a reference to the dom element. `.focus()` [does not have a return and only shifts focus to the element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus). You should try `wantEmailAndUpdatesRef.current.checked`.

Comment: it's Still not working, when i go to the next page which is defined in the same file it shows again ```cannot read property of null reading (checked)```

Comment: do you put html and useRef in same comnponent?

Comment: yes it's an functional component and both of them are in the same component